# Слетел перевод на странице восстановления пароля

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, восстановление-аккаунта

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переводы добавлены. Уже доступны на сайте.

> [image]